# Ive just installed lubuntu on my old thinkpad and its running out of space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, disk-usage

My thinkpad laptop has 3 drives (or partitions, I'm not sure. It's like having a C, D and E drive on Windows or having a /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3 on Linux). Each one is about 15-20 GB. 
I installed Lubuntu by booting it off of my usb and installing it. However, now when I want to install something, it tells me I'm running out of space.

The first drive and the third drive look like they are filled with stuff from Windows installed of my computer. The second drive is completely empty.

How can I find out which drive the software is being installed on? Deleting things from any of the 3 drives doesn't seem to have an affect on the "remaining space" when it gives me the not enough space error message. The only thing that frees up space is when I uninstall something.

Comment: The softwares would be installed in the default location i.e., in the drive where ubuntu is installed

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool like Baobab to monitor the Disc Usage. This will show you which Files take up the most space on your system. Deleting files on your Windows drive won't free up space for your ubuntu installation because per default Windows can't read the lubuntu filesystem.

Did you use any custom partition at the installation of leave everything at default?

[Baobab | Disk Usage Analyzer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Baobab)

Comment: I think I left everything at default.

Comment: To check the disk-usage you could run `df -h` in a terminal and paste the output. It'll tell us which drive / partition has no space left.